# Amazon s3 implementation in php not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to integrate amazon api for uploading content directly. When I integrate this I got an error:

```
$aws_key    = example key;
$aws_secret = example secret key;

$source_file = 'test.jpg'; // file to upload to S3

$file_type = "image/jpg";  // or other file type like "image/jpeg" for JPEG image, 
// or "binary/octet-stream" for binary file

$aws_bucket = 'bucket_example'; // AWS bucket 
$aws_object = 'test.jpg';         // AWS object name (file name)


if (strlen($aws_secret) != 40) die("$aws_secret should be exactly 40 bytes long");
$file_data = file_get_contents($source_file);
if ($file_data == false) die("Failed to read file ".$source_file);


// opening HTTP connection to Amazon S3
$fp = fsockopen("s3.amazonaws.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    die("$errstr ($errno)\n");
}
```

I got this error:

> AmazonS3 2eb SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I double check the keys. There is no mistake in keys.

Comment: Where are you providing keys to amazon? You are only opening socket there without any data.

Comment: I suggest using the official [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) to integrate with Amazon S3.

Comment: Agreed with @JeremyLindblom. Here's the example usage : https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/issues/94#issuecomment-284131630

Comment: Refer to this article if you want a more simple example: https://medium.com/@kentaguilar/simplest-way-to-upload-a-file-to-aws-s3-via-php-e83a9f54ba77